# Sending HBITMAP over socket giving problems

Tags: c++, sockets, bitmap

So im trying to send a HBITMAP over socket, and comming to some issues.
I know that HBITMAP is a handle, a memory reference pointer to the image bytes.
So what i did, was lookup on google how to convert it to a byte array, and therefore be able to send it:

```
void *pktdata;
std::vector<uint8_t> pixels;

uint32_t width;
uint32_t height;
uint16_t BitsPerPixel;

HBITMAPToPixels(texture, pixels, width, height, BitsPerPixel);

int pktsize = sizeof(PKT_Structure_s) + sizeof(std::vector<uint8_t>) + (sizeof(uint8_t) * pixels.size());

PKT_Structure_s n;
n.width = width;
n.height = height;
n.BitsPerPixel = BitsPerPixel;
n.DataSize = sizeof(std::vector<uint8_t>) + (sizeof(uint8_t) * pixels.size());

memcpy(&pktdata, &n, sizeof(n));
memcpy(&pktdata + sizeof(n), &pixels, n.DataSize);

p2pSendToHost(NULL, (DefaultPacket*)pktdata, pktsize);
delete[] pktdata;
return;
```

And this is the HBITMAPToPixels i got from another stackoverflor question:

```
void HBITMAPToPixels(HBITMAP BitmapHandle, std::vector<uint8_t> &Pixels, uint32_t &width, uint32_t &height, uint16_t &BitsPerPixel) 
{

if (BitmapHandle == NULL)
{
    throw std::logic_error("Null Pointer Exception. BitmapHandle is Null.");
}

Pixels.clear();
BITMAP Bmp = { 0 };
BITMAPINFO Info = { 0 };
HDC DC = CreateCompatibleDC(NULL);
std::memset(&Info, 0, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));
HBITMAP OldBitmap = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(DC, BitmapHandle);
GetObject(BitmapHandle, sizeof(Bmp), &Bmp);

Info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
Info.bmiHeader.biWidth = width = Bmp.bmWidth;
Info.bmiHeader.biHeight = height = Bmp.bmHeight;
Info.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
Info.bmiHeader.biBitCount = BitsPerPixel = Bmp.bmBitsPixel;
Info.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
Info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = ((width * Bmp.bmBitsPixel + 31) / 32) * 4 * height;

Pixels.resize(Info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage);
GetDIBits(DC, BitmapHandle, 0, height, &Pixels[0], &Info, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
SelectObject(DC, OldBitmap);
height = height < 0 ? -height : height;
DeleteDC(DC);

}
```

And this is crashing sometimes, and sometimes it actually sends the packet but the server then crashes.
This is how the server handles the packet:

```
void Server::ProcessScreenShot(const void * packetdatadata, int packetsizesize)
{
PKT_Structure_sn;
std::vector<uint8_t> pixels;
int pktsize = sizeof(PKT_Structure_s) + sizeof(std::vector<uint8_t>) + (sizeof(uint8_t) * pixels.size());

memcpy(&n, packetdatadata, sizeof(n)); //Get Our Packet Struct
memcpy(&pixels, &packetdatadata + sizeof(n), n.DataSize); // Get Our Image in bytes

HBITMAP btmp = HBITMAPFromPixels(pixels, n.width, n.height, n.BitsPerPixel);

time_t t = time(0);
struct tm * now = localtime(&t);

char filename[MAX_PATH];
sprintf(filename, "SS.bmp");

HPALETTE hpal = NULL;
saveBitmap(filename, btmp, hpal);

return;
}
```

And last but not least, the other function i used from the question answer to get my HBITMAP back:

```
HBITMAP HBITMAPFromPixels(const std::vector<uint8_t> &Pixels, uint32_t width, uint32_t height, uint16_t BitsPerPixel)
{
BITMAPINFO Info = { 0 };
std::memset(&Info, 0, sizeof(BITMAPINFO));

Info.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
Info.bmiHeader.biWidth = width;
Info.bmiHeader.biHeight = -height;
Info.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
Info.bmiHeader.biBitCount = BitsPerPixel;
Info.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
Info.bmiHeader.biSizeImage = ((width * BitsPerPixel + 31) / 32) * 4 * height;

HBITMAP Result = CreateDIBitmap(GetDC(NULL), &Info.bmiHeader, CBM_INIT, &Pixels[0], &Info, DIB_RGB_COLORS);
return Result;
}
```

And the save function is irrelevant, since ive tested it on a console app really quick and it works.

I think i might be doing wrong by memcpy as i got really confused while doing that, which is probs crashing.

Thanks

Comment: Run it in the debugger and narrow down where the crash is.

Comment: Yeah thats the problem. I cant debug it since its compiled on a server and will most probabbly not even be able to run the game, and i tried remotedebug but never got it working.

Comment: If you converted it to bytes, you're not sending an HBITMAP over the socket at all, you're sending the bytes. So your title is wrong. Or at least you're trying to do that. Where exactly are you allocating `pktdata`? Hint: you aren't.

Comment: There's nothing stopping you from running both the server and client on your development machine while you're debugging.

Comment: Yes, the server has a bad graphic card, so running the game in it just freezes  the entire thing. Regarding pktdata, what do you mean with allocating?

Comment: @user3609253 It is customary to initialize variables prior to using them. You aren't doing that. You're passing its address to `memcpy(),` twice, and then to `delete[]`, but there is no corresponding allocation. The code you've written doesn't make sense.

Comment: @EJP I wouldn't call it "customary".

Comment: @immibis Neither would I. It's a joke, Joyce.

Comment: Yeah i was doing memcpy wrong, i just fixed it in the code i think. Testing now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not initializing pkdata and passing the vector wrong, u have to pass it like
     &vec[0]